# What is the name of the part, often seen on BMX bicycles, that allows an additional rider on the back the bike?

Tags: parts, bmx

What is the name of the part, often seen on BMX bicycles, that allows an additional rider on the back the bike? It appears to be a set of relatively short but thick poles that go on either side of the axle of the rear wheel so a passenger can stand on it and—holding onto the shoulders of the driver—can be transported with minimal effort.

What is that part called?

Comment: I believe the correct term is "homie haulers" which is what they do get used for quite often.

Comment: You thought pegs were for other people to ride on? Do you live in a cave?

Answer (score 27):

They are called **Pegs.**

Pegs are mainly used by BMX riders to help perform various tricks.

Flatland trick (standing with all of his weight on one peg, not damaging anything):
[image]

Grinding a wall on the rear peg (imagine the forces when the rider jumps on the wall, still: no damage to the hub but of course to the peg and the wall):
[image]

Images from [Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bmx_santa_monica_beach.jpg) [Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Feeble-Ledge-Grind.jpg)

Comment: Yes, that's what they are called. They aren't meant for another person to stand on.

Comment: +1 for Kibbee's comment, specifically they are NOT designed for someone to stand on. They are designed for trick riding (grinds, etc.)

Comment: Yes, but probably 4x as many are used for the second rider as are used for doing tricks.

Comment: That really isn't true, at least outside of grade school. And it really does damage your bike. Not at all recommended.

Comment: It does **not** damage your bike at all. Read my comment to your answer.

Comment: We called them croggies when I was a kid. There must be a hundred different names for them though.

Answer (score 10):

They are called pegs. Designed for tricks, in a BMX park or Flatland style. And they are not meant for another person to stand on.

Quite the opposite. It is dangerous to ride a second person in that manner. And you risk damage to the hub of the bike, since the axle can bend or break.

Comment: -1. You probably wont damage to the hub of the bike, since the axle will not bend or break from a person standing still on the pegs. Have you ever seen a BMX rider jumping on a rail or the coping of a halfpipe? I think that is much more power (impulse). It is the weight of the rider + the bike + the drop on the rail (metal to metal). Not a soft shoe stepping carefully on the pegs. Flatlanders are standing all the time on their pegs!

Comment: @Erik, yes, I have.  I've also seen a number of axles which break for those reasons, also.  Pros get paid to ride, and can afford to break both their bikes and there bodies.  This is a primary reason why many axles were upgraded to 14mm from 9.5mm, back in about 1995.

Comment: Ah, your experience is from 1995, that explains your opinion. :-) Today nobody uses 14mm axles but 10mm. And the axles don’t break. The material properties have improved.

Comment: @Erik, I have been working in bike shops as a mechanic since 1992 to current.  Most of our bikes in the shop, as of today are 14mm axles, at least on the rear. The front is more of a choice.  The front axle isn't 10mm, it's 3/8" or 9.5mm.  And the material properties of cro-moly and high carbon steel  haven't changed, but thanks for your condescension.

Comment: If you want to bug me: An inch is 2,54cm, hence 9,525mm. Which kind of bikes do you sell or repair? BMX bikes? You mean the cheap ones (sold for 100 Euros)? Then maybe you’re right. They surely brake more often then real BMX bikes.

Comment: Btw. most of the BMX riders aren’t pros, and neither are they paid. Please, visit a skate park and watch the riders. Or watch some flatland BMX riders, standing all the time on one or two pegs. But if you put axle pegs on city bikes, then that would be dangerous, of course. Did you mean that?

Comment: @Erik, I'm not going to argue with you.  If you know bikes, you know this is unsafe.  If you don't, then you can say whatever you like.  I will not respond to you further.

Comment: When I was a lad, I had pegs on the rear axle that I regularly used to double mates all over town with. Over a period of about four years, almost every school day, I had someone on the back for the trip home from school, doing all kinds of crazy and stupid things. I NEVER had a problem with damage to the axle or hub of the rear wheel.